# $\prod_{i=1}^n (i+n)$ - To what does it converges?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I try to prove that $\sum^n_{k=0} {n\choose k}^2 = {2n \choose n} $, but a given moment during the proof, I am faced with the product $\prod_{i=1}^n (i+n)$ that I am not able to solve. Does someone could tell me how to converge the equation?

Comment: The product doesn't converge to anything, but you may rewrite it as $(2n)!/n!.$

Comment: Why can we rewrite it as $2n!/n!$?

Comment: Well, the product is of consecutive whole positive numbers, the greatest of which is $2n$ and the least of which is $n+1$. The factorial allows us to write products of whole numbers from $1$ to $m$. So, if you want the product from $m'$ to $m$ you can write that as $m!/(m'-1)!$. Here, that makes it $(2n)!/n!$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that

$$\prod_{i=1}^n(i+n)=(1+n)(2+n)\cdots(2n)\ge n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\infty$$

Comment: I already know that, but thank for your effort